# Python Pandas select group where a specific column contains zeroes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a small project using Python Pandas and I'm stuck at the following problem:

I have a table where column A contains multiple and possibly non unique values and a second column B with values which might be zero. Now I want to group all rows in the DataFrame by their value in column A and then only "keep" or "select" the groups which contain one or more zeros in the B column.

For example from a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Column A    Column B
--------    --------
b           12
c           56
f           0
b           456
b           334
f           10
```

I am only interested in all rows (the group) where column A = f :

```
Column A    Column B
--------    --------
f           0
f           10
```

I know how I could achieve this using loops and iterating over groups but I'm looking for a simple and reasonably fast code as the DataFrames I work with can get very huge.

My current approach is something like this:

```
df.groupby("A").filter(lambda x: 0 in x["B"].values)
```

Obviously I'm new to Python Pandas and am hoping for your help !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: how about using `query`, `df.query("columnA == 'f'").query("columnB >= 0")`

Comment: @titipat Thank you for your reply. In your solution I would have to know all possible values in Column A before and somehow iterate them using a loop, right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. If you wan to iterate through, `groupby` is probably a better to go rather than my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to get all values of column A where column B is zero, and then group on this filtered set.

```
groups = df[df['Column B'] == 0]['Column A'].unique()
>>> df[df['Column A'].isin(groups)]
  Column A  Column B
2        f         0
5        f        10
```